# Issues with compiling C code in Linux GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am currently have two problems while compiling my code.

The first is that I keep getting this error when I compile my C code through terminal on Visual Studio;

```
in function `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am currently using this command to compile:

```
gcc -Wall -g filename.c -o filename
```

My code in main is this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned int M = atoi(argv[1]);
    unsigned int N = atoi(argv[2]);
    
    matrixArrayOfArrays(M, N);
      
    return 0;
}
```

My second issue is that when I do get a file to work and compile, whenever I make change to that file and rerun the compiler using the same commands as above, it does not make the changes to the code. I have been looking for hours on this and have had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried creating new files through terminal and through Visual Studio. I have tried different ways to compile the program as well.

Comment: _"when I do get a file to work and compile"_ - sort of nullifies the first part of your question. Just remove that part.

Comment: @Fe2O3 It is not named main, but the file has a .c extension.

Comment: Are you certain you are saving the file before you compile?

Comment: @RetiredNinja No I am not sure, what is the command for this in the terminal? I truly believe this is the problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the terminal. You need to save in your editor.

Comment: Thank you... I appreciate you dealing with my stupidity. This is officially solved. Just to be clear, there is no other way to save it auto, I have to manually hit CTRL+S every time before I compile and run.

Comment: I don't know of a way to make it automatic but I don't use that editor. I've done it so long I don't even realize I am saving the file anymore, I just make a change and hit save automatically.

Comment: See [Auto Save in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/suffer-from-ctrls-fatigue-we-have-a-feature-for-you/)